# Matplotlib Legend on Scatterplot from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to get the legend right on the figure below. It should be just 'green', 'blue' and 'red' with the corresponding color. But it is all over the place.
[image]

the code is below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'category':['blue','green','red','blue','green','red','blue','green','red'],
        'attempts':[8955,7881,6723,100,200,300,4567,876,54],
        'success':[3000,7500,2000, 256,4567,4567,7665,543,43]
})
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(df['attempts'],df['success'],c=df['category'],label=df['category'])
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.savefig('scatter.png')
plt.show()
```

How do I get this right? 
(There is a similar one here: https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-scatterplot/ in the second part "Scatter plot with groups", but this is not based on pandas dataframe).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use seaborn's `scatterplot`:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, hue='category', x='attempts', y='success')
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.savefig('scatter.png')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: enter code here]

Or pure matplotlib:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for k,d in df.groupby('category'):
    ax.scatter(d['attempts'], d['success'], label=k)
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.savefig('scatter.png')
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I never knew about being able to use groupby like this. Is there a weblink or some document you can refer to where I can read about this? Not just in the context of plotting but in any other context in which it might be useful

Comment: This is from [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), the `groupby()` returns a `GroupBy` [object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html) that has an `__iter__()` method, which allows `for ... in`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use a single scatter with matplotlib, it would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'category':['blue','green','red','blue','green','red','blue','green','red'],
        'attempts':[8955,7881,6723,100,200,300,4567,876,54],
        'success':[3000,7500,2000, 256,4567,4567,7665,543,43]
})

u, inv = np.unique(df.category.values, return_inverse=True)
cmap = ListedColormap(u)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = plt.scatter(df['attempts'],df['success'],c=inv, cmap=cmap)
plt.legend(scatter.legend_elements()[0], u, loc=2)
plt.savefig('scatter.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]