# Plot legend only showing one element

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following data:

```
   a  b  col lab
0  1  6    1   a
1  4  5    2   b
2  1  7    3   c
3  5  5    4   d
4  6  2    5   e
```

My goal here is to plot a scatter of [a] and [b] and have each value of col be different colors and have a legend that mnaps the color to the label.

I tried the following, but it only shows the legend for the first element.

```
plt.scatter(df['a'], df['b'], c = df['col'])
plt.legend(df['lab'])
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37813290/2943652

Comment: it is giving you only one legend because the method `plt.scatter` is being called only once

Comment: ahh gotcha.  I'm more familiar with R so I guess I expected matplotlib to work simiarly to ggplot.  So I must loop through each datapoint.

Comment: My dataframe actually has about 8k datapoints.  Is this prohibitive to plot in a loop?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000327/4124317); [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56507383/4124317);  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394204/pandas-groupby-scatter-plot-in-a-single-plot/56394972#56394972);  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58449842/4124317)

Comment: I'm getting the following error when replicating the first answer mentioned in the thread:
Image size of 380x121747 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.
\